# [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load doesn't load the content

Tags: powershell, .net-assembly, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to execute an exe file from the Internet:

```
$bytes = (Invoke-WebRequest "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/frankwick/t/main/tinytask.exe" ).Content
$assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)
```

but it crashes on Load with this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly '36352 bytes loaded from Anonymously
Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An
attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Check the status of the response.  You probably are not getting 200 OK,  Instead a 400 or 500 error and then the body (contents) would be empty.

Comment: No, I am getting byte[] with many bytes inside. Also, I've tried other URLs with the same result

Comment: Are you sure ```tinytask.exe``` is actually a dotnet assembly, and not a native executable?

Comment: No, I'm not... I didn't think there're should be .NET, not any exe